# Buildroot 'make <pkg>-rebuild' same as 'make <pkg>'?

Tags: makefile, buildroot

On a Buildroot managed project I'd just checked-out, I've run `<pkg>-rebuild` by mistake instead of `make all` followed by `make <pkg>-rebuild`.

When I found out my mistake, I was surprised the build had gone smoothly, without error, just as if I had run `make all` followed by `make <pkg>-rebuild` as suggested in the documentation available in my company for this package.

I'm totally new to Buildroot, and I was wondering: is it expected behavior for all Buildroot managed projects? In other words, can I continue to just run `make <pkg>-rebuild` instead of `make all` followed by `make <pkg>-rebuild`?

---

**EDIT**: in other words, *for a package never built before*, should `make <pkg>-rebuild` have the very same effect as `make <pkg>`?

---

Note : I didn't find the answer in the Buildroot user manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make <pkg>` builds:

- all the dependencies of `<pkg>` that have not been built yet
- `<pkg>` if it has not been built yet

So, if `make <pkg>` is executed twice in a row, the second call will do nothing.

`make <pkg>-rebuild` builds:

- all the dependencies of `<pkg>` that have not been built yet
  (same as above)
- The `build` and the following steps for `<pkg>`,
  no matter if they have already been done

So, if `make <pkg>-rebuild` is executed twice in a row, the second call will not run the extract, patch and configure steps, but it will execute the build and install steps.

`make <pkg>-rebuild` is used for example when you edit the package build recipe in `<pkg>/<pkg>.mk` and you want to build it again with the new rules.

Comment: Isn't this answer off-topic ? The question is about `make <pkg>-rebuild` as compared to `make <pkg>`...

Comment: Sorry. I edited the answer. I think it now fits the question.